# mlpy, numpy, scipy on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numpy, scipy

Can MlPy / SciPy be used on GAE?

I believe I have imported NumPy correctly, as it does not raise any errors so far (GAE 1.6 ships with support for NumPy). However, From what I've read, I still need to import SciPy and MlPy, and I haven't been able to do it so far. Is there any documentation out there that could explain accurately how to setup MlPy on GAE (if this is even possible)?

The main reason as to why I need MlPy is that I need to do a k-means analysis (finding a cluster center point). Isn't there a "lite" library to do this that would avoid all the hassle of setting up NumPy and MlPy?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to import scipy. What I did is:

1. Downloaded [scipy-0.11.0b1.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.11.0b1/scipy-0.11.0b1.tar.gz/download)
2. Extracted the 'scipy' folder into my GAE App folder
3. From a python file, call 'import scipy'

The error that I get is:

```
ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while
        being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source
        tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libraries written in pure Python that don't require C modules should be supported.

Libraries written in Python that utilize C modules **MAY** be supported. The following is a link to supported and not-supported C modules. This may help in determining whether or not the library you want to use will be supported.

[Google App Engine Python Library Support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27)